# Stacked and Clustered Columns Excel

Tags: excel, finance

I am trying to recreate the below chart in excel:

[image]

Below is the data I am using, it is the same data used to generate the chart.

[image]

I can't seem to get the desired output, the data stacks but does not separate into the asset classes as expected, an example of which is below:

[image]

Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: Changing it to box-n-whiskers chart (and maybe getting rid of row 2) will get you real close. Then format as necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the box & whisker version of your chart, with some minor editing after the conversion...

[image]